# Outlook Custom Form Sharing

Tags: vba, outlook

I have designed a custom form on Outlook Calendars and I am looking to share it with other users within the organization. I published the form to a public folder associated with the calendar, but others do not have access. Is there an easy way to make this form public/accessible to all users?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Outlook forms can be published to three different types of form "libraries":

- Personal Forms Library of forms stored in your Personal Folders or Exchange Server mailbox.
- Organizational Forms Library of forms stored on the Exchange Server for group use. You need permission from the Exchange Server administrator to publish to this library.
- Folder Forms Library of forms associated with a particular folder, either in your mailbox or Personal Folders or in a public folder on the Exchange Server.
  When a form is published to a folder, it's listed on the Actions menu when you are using that folder. To use the form, click on Actions, .

Read more about that in the [Publishing Custom Forms](https://www.slipstick.com/developer/publishing-custom-forms/) article.

The [How to determine where to publish a custom Outlook form](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/troubleshoot/user-interface/how-to-determine-where-to-publish-custom-outlook-forms) article can help you to decide where to publish the form.